# Does TypeScript have something like C#'s dynamic type?

Tags: typescript

Does TypeScript have something like C#'s `dynamic` type?

I need that dynamic aspect because TypeScript has the `any` type. Inside, I upload one JSON file, and I would like to access in some variable to their values of JSON class mapped to model.

[watch here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Is it possible in TypeScript?

My code:

```
loadData(index: any) {
    this._service.GetTreeViewModel(index).subscribe((items) => {                                                    
        this.items = items[0].**items**;
     });
}
```

It is giving me a compilation error:

> ERROR in C:/_PRJ/mappingtools/src/app/iui-Tools/Tree/Tree.component.ts (42,21): Type 'any[]' cannot be converted to type 'items'.)
>   C:/_PRJ/mappingtools/src/app/iui-Tools/Tree/Tree.component.ts (42,21): Type 'any[]' cannot be converted to type 'items'.
>     Property 'items' is missing in type 'any[]'.)

And my object is:

```
{
    id:1,
    items: [...]
}
```

I can't access items when I do something like `x.items`.

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, so actually every variable is `dynamic` - maybe you want to declare a variable as `any` type?

Comment: I have any variable which I need one filed inside called items

Comment: So what is the problem when you declare it as `any` type? What errors do you receive? (Also please show the code that is causing the issues)

Comment: it is curious what you say is right but VS Code compiler says: ERROR in Property 'items' does not exist on type 'any[]'.) in Chrome is ok when I make items.items

Comment: Without seeing any actual code this question cannot be answered - please expand your problem description and provide a [mcve]

Comment: done I changed the question with more information.

Comment: What is `this.items`?

Comment: public items: Array<any>;

Comment: ok closed problem was Array... DBA changed query and now is any not Array<any>